# Execute hive query cause yarn resource manager to throw file does not exist exception

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

I'm configuring hive 3.1.0 to work with hadoop 3.0.0.
This error throw almost immediately when I submit a simple query on beeline that cause map reduce

```
0: jdbc:hive2://> select count(*) from airlinedata;
18/10/11 10:24:45 [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-124]: WARN ql.Driver: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the futureversions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
Query ID = UUT81HC_20181011102444_2df01ff5-ca05-403c-b0e1-15f8f7715dc7
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=
2018-10-11 10:24:45,510 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-124] client.RMProxy (RMProxy.java:newProxyInstance(133)) - Connecting to ResourceManager at /10.184.153.232:8032
2018-10-11 10:24:45,555 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-124] client.RMProxy (RMProxy.java:newProxyInstance(133)) - Connecting to ResourceManager at /10.184.153.232:8032
18/10/11 10:24:45 [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-124]: WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
WARN  : Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RecordFactoryPBImpl.newRecordInstance(RecordFactoryPBImpl.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TypeConverter.toYarn(TypeConverter.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.(ClientServiceDelegate.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientCache.getClient(ClientCache.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.submitJob(YARNRunner.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1570)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1567)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1962)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1567)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:576)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:571)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1962)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:571)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:562)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:97)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2664)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:2335)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:2011)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1709)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.run(ReExecDriver.java:157)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:224)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$700(SQLOperation.java:87)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:316)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1962)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:329)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RecordFactoryPBImpl.newRecordInstance(RecordFactoryPBImpl.java:70)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/proto/MRProtos$JobIdProto$Builder.setAppId(Lorg/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/proto/MRProtos$JobIdProto$Builder; @36: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @36
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/proto/MRProtos$JobIdProto$Builder', 'org/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto' }
    stack: { 'com/google/protobuf/SingleFieldBuilder', 'org/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0011 c700 1b2b c700 0bbb 002f 59b7
    0x0000010: 0030 bf2a 2bb5 000a 2ab6 0031 a700 0c2a
    0x0000020: b400 112b b600 3257 2a59 b400 1304 80b5
    0x0000030: 0013 2ab0
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@19)
    same_frame(@31)
    same_frame(@40)

        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.proto.MRProtos$JobIdProto.newBuilder(MRProtos.java:1017)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.records.impl.pb.JobIdPBImpl.(JobIdPBImpl.java:37)
        ... 45 more
```

yarn resoucemanager stacktrace

```
2018-10-11 10:24:49,896 INFO rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1539226955170_0002 State change from ACCEPTED to FINAL_SAVING on event = ATTEMPT_FAILED
2018-10-11 10:24:49,896 INFO recovery.RMStateStore: Updating info for app: application_1539226955170_0002
2018-10-11 10:24:49,897 INFO capacity.CapacityScheduler: Application Attempt appattempt_1539226955170_0002_000002 is done. finalState=FAILED
2018-10-11 10:24:49,897 INFO rmapp.RMAppImpl: Application application_1539226955170_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1539226955170_0002_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2018-10-11 10:24:49.876]File does not exist: hdfs://10.184.153.232:19000/tmp/hive/UUT81HC/0d321851-1d90-4f19-ac50-12d120da601d/hive_2018-10-11_10-24-44_868_5772391105026287697-3/-mr-10005/b8800c0f-f09c-41ca-ab69-a79b72fc9597/reduce.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://10.184.153.232:19000/tmp/hive/UUT81HC/0d321851-1d90-4f19-ac50-12d120da601d/hive_2018-10-11_10-24-44_868_5772391105026287697-3/-mr-10005/b8800c0f-f09c-41ca-ab69-a79b72fc9597/reduce.xml
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1495)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1488)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1503)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:364)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1962)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.doDownloadCall(ContainerLocalizer.java:241)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.call(ContainerLocalizer.java:234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.call(ContainerLocalizer.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://HC-UT40048C.apac.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1539226955170_0002 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
2018-10-11 10:24:49,897 INFO scheduler.AppSchedulingInfo: Application application_1539226955170_0002 requests cleared
2018-10-11 10:24:49,897 INFO rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1539226955170_0002 State change from FINAL_SAVING to FAILED on event = APP_UPDATE_SAVED
2018-10-11 10:24:49,898 INFO capacity.LeafQueue: Application removed - appId: application_1539226955170_0002 user: UUT81HC queue: default #user-pending-applications: 0 #user-active-applications: 0 #queue-pending-applications: 0 #queue-active-applications: 0
2018-10-11 10:24:49,898 WARN resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=UUT81HC        OPERATION=Application Finished - Failed
TARGET=RMAppManager     RESULT=FAILURE  DESCRIPTION=App failed with state: FAILED       PERMISSIONS=Application application_1539226955170_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1539226955170_0002_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2018-10-11 10:24:49.876]File does not exist: hdfs://10.184.153.232:19000/tmp/hive/UUT81HC/0d321851-1d90-4f19-ac50-12d120da601d/hive_2018-10-11_10-24-44_868_5772391105026287697-3/-mr-10005/b8800c0f-f09c-41ca-ab69-a79b72fc9597/reduce.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://10.184.153.232:19000/tmp/hive/UUT81HC/0d321851-1d90-4f19-ac50-12d120da601d/hive_2018-10-11_10-24-44_868_5772391105026287697-3/-mr-10005/b8800c0f-f09c-41ca-ab69-a79b72fc9597/reduce.xml
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1495)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1488)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1503)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:364)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1962)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.doDownloadCall(ContainerLocalizer.java:241)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.call(ContainerLocalizer.java:234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.call(ContainerLocalizer.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://HC-UT40048C.apac.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1539226955170_0002 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.      APPID=application_1539226955170_0002
2018-10-11 10:24:49,898 INFO capacity.ParentQueue: Application removed - appId: application_1539226955170_0002 user: UUT81HC leaf-queue of parent: root #applications: 0
2018-10-11 10:24:49,899 INFO resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary: appId=application_1539226955170_0002,name=select count(*) from airlinedata (Stage-1),user=UUT81HC,queue=default,state=FAILED,trackingUrl=http://HC-UT40048C.apac.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1539226955170_0002,appMasterHost=N/A,submitTime=1539228287412,startTime=1539228287413,finishTime=1539228289896,finalStatus=FAILED,memorySeconds=1482,vcoreSeconds=0,preemptedMemorySeconds=0,preemptedVcoreSeconds=0,preemptedAMContainers=0,preemptedNonAMContainers=0,preemptedResources=,applicationType=MAPREDUCE,resourceSeconds=1482 MB-seconds\, 0 vcore-seconds,preemptedResourceSeconds=0 MB-seconds\, 0 vcore-seconds
```

After examine how hive execute mapreduce job on yarn, I found that it first it create map.xml and reduce.xml in /tmp with permission drwx------ (only owner can use it)

```
2018-10-11 10:24:45,133 INFO hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* allocate blk_1073742318_1495, replicas=10.184.153.232:9866 for /tmp/hive/UUT81HC/0d321851-1d90-4f19-ac50-12d120da601d/hive_2018-10-11_10-24-44_868_5772391105026287697-3/-mr-10005/b8800c0f-f09c-41ca-ab69-a79b72fc9597/map.xml
2018-10-11 10:24:45,225 INFO hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /tmp/hive/UUT81HC/0d321851-1d90-4f19-ac50-12d120da601d/hive_2018-10-11_10-24-44_868_5772391105026287697-3/-mr-10005/b8800c0f-f09c-41ca-ab69-a79b72fc9597/map.xml is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_164506931_1
2018-10-11 10:24:45,248 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: Increasing replication from 2 to 10 for /tmp/hive/UUT81HC/0d321851-1d90-4f19-ac50-12d120da601d/hive_2018-10-11_10-24-44_868_5772391105026287697-3/-mr-10005/b8800c0f-f09c-41ca-ab69-a79b72fc9597/map.xml
2018-10-11 10:24:45,294 INFO hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* allocate blk_1073742319_1496, replicas=10.184.153.232:9866 for /tmp/hive/UUT81HC/0d321851-1d90-4f19-ac50-12d120da601d/hive_2018-10-11_10-24-44_868_5772391105026287697-3/-mr-10005/b8800c0f-f09c-41ca-ab69-a79b72fc9597/reduce.xml
2018-10-11 10:24:45,411 INFO hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /tmp/hive/UUT81HC/0d321851-1d90-4f19-ac50-12d120da601d/hive_2018-10-11_10-24-44_868_5772391105026287697-3/-mr-10005/b8800c0f-f09c-41ca-ab69-a79b72fc9597/reduce.xml is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_164506931_1
2018-10-11 10:24:45,437 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: Increasing replication from 2 to 10 for /tmp/hive/UUT81HC/0d321851-1d90-4f19-ac50-12d120da601d/hive_2018-10-11_10-24-44_868_5772391105026287697-3/-mr-10005/b8800c0f-f09c-41ca-ab69-a79b72fc9597/reduce.xml
2018-10-11 10:24:45,772 INFO hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* allocate blk_1073742320_1497, replicas=10.184.153.232:9866 for /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/UUT81HC/.staging/job_1539226955170_0002/job.jar
2018-10-11 10:24:46,438 INFO hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/UUT81HC/.staging/job_1539226955170_0002/job.jar is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_164506931_1
2018-10-11 10:24:46,463 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: Increasing replication from 2 to 10 for /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/UUT81HC/.staging/job_1539226955170_0002/job.jar
2018-10-11 10:24:46,618 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: Increasing replication from 2 to 10 for /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/UUT81HC/.staging/job_1539226955170_0002/job.split
2018-10-11 10:24:46,639 INFO hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* allocate blk_1073742321_1498, replicas=10.184.153.232:9866 for /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/UUT81HC/.staging/job_1539226955170_0002/job.split
2018-10-11 10:24:46,706 INFO hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/UUT81HC/.staging/job_1539226955170_0002/job.split is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_164506931_1
2018-10-11 10:24:46,791 INFO hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* allocate blk_1073742322_1499, replicas=10.184.153.232:9866 for /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/UUT81HC/.staging/job_1539226955170_0002/job.splitmetainfo
2018-10-11 10:24:46,870 INFO hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/UUT81HC/.staging/job_1539226955170_0002/job.splitmetainfo is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_164506931_1
2018-10-11 10:24:46,971 INFO hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* allocate blk_1073742323_1500, replicas=10.184.153.232:9866 for /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/UUT81HC/.staging/job_1539226955170_0002/job.xml
2018-10-11 10:24:47,370 INFO hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/UUT81HC/.staging/job_1539226955170_0002/job.xml is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_164506931_1
2018-10-11 10:32:15,741 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: StorageInfo TreeSet fill ratio DS-d4c2a5a0-435d-4b44-b408-3cd04587cd09 : 1.0
```

But somehow yarn can't read that when executing job and throw out file does not exist. I did set permission 777 on /tmp but this file is self create by hive in executing process so I can't do anything with it.

I doubt that this problem is something related to user or permission when using hive in hadoop. What should I do with this?